# Printing pdf file with VBA is not doing anything

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to print external pdf files from MS-Access using VBA.

I use this command:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName("file_to_print.pdf").InvokeVerb("Print")
```

Printing with this command text files (*.txt) works fine, but pdf does not.

The context menu when right clicking on the pdf file has no print Option:

[image]]

The context menu of the text file has a print command. I read somewhere that this is needed for the above printing to work.

Any solution for this?

I use Windows 10, and Acrobat Reader is installed.

Comment: If you have Adobe Acrobat Pro (not reader), you can use COM automation to achieve this. If you don't, you can't reliably automate actions on PDFs (barring hacky solutions using Internet Explorer to open the PDF file and print it).

Comment: We use FoxIt PDF to view an print PDFs. It is fast and handy.

Comment: This seems to be an issue of the Foxit installation. Maybe try to reinstall it? You wrote "Acrobat Reader is installed". So only one of both can have the 'print' verb. Maybe the current situation came from having both installed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, the problem was that the default application for pdf was Microsoft Edge, I changed it to Acrobat Reader, and now it is printing.